# VSTS-Task-Lib exec function strips out quotes

Tags: javascript, msbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a custom TFS 2015 build task that will call msbuild with certain properties that need surrounding quotes ("").

**Problem Statement** - quotes are being removed somewhere between the tl.exec call and the actual command line execution which breaks the command.

Here is the snippet of typescript code causing problem:

```
let msbuildArgs = "AssemblyInfoUpdater.proj /p:SearchRoot=" + searchRoot
                  + ";IncludePattern=\"" + includePattern
                  + "\";Major=" + tl.getVariable("Major")
                  + ";Minor=" + tl.getVariable("Minor")
                  + ";Build=" + tl.getVariable("Build")
                  + ";Revision=" + tl.getVariable("Revision")
                  + ";BinariesRoot=" + tl.getVariable("Build.BinariesDirectory")
                  + ";TeamProject="+ tl.getVariable("System.TeamProject");

let result = tl.exec(`${tl.getVariable("MSBuild")}\\msbuild.exe`, msbuildArgs);
```

As you can see, IncludePattern needs to be surrounded by quotes (hence the escaped quote (\")).

Here is the result I get when running it:

```
##vso[task.debug]exec tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe
##vso[task.debug]Arguments:
##vso[task.debug] AssemblyInfoUpdater.proj
##vso[task.debug] /p:SearchRoot=d:\Git\agent-tasks\Tests\AssemblyInfoUpdater\build\src;IncludePattern=**\assemblyinfo.*;Major=2;Minor=3;Build=100;Revision=50;BinariesRoot=d:\Git\agent-tasks\Tests\AssemblyInfoUpdater\build\bin;TeamProject=Synergis
[command]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe AssemblyInfoUpdater.proj /p:SearchRoot=d:\Git\agent-tasks\Tests\AssemblyInfoUpdater\build\src;IncludePattern=**\assemblyinfo.*;Major=2;Minor=3;Build=100;Revision=50;BinariesRoot=d:\Git\agent-tasks\Tests\AssemblyInfoUpdater\build\bin;TeamProject=Synergis
```

The quotes are stripped out and msbuild fails due to invalid parameters.

Any ideas on how I can keep the quotes?

Comment: Which one are you using the tfs 2015 or the vsteam -service(vsonline)?

Comment: tfs 2015 update 2 on-premise with agent version 1.95.0 and vsts-task-lib version 0.7.2

Comment: How about using "/p:" for all the arguments like: /p:SearchRoot=xxxx /p:IncludePattern=xxxx ...?